# Suppose A and B are two events. Show that the following are equivalent...

Tags: probability, proof-writing

Suppose A and B are two events. Show that the following are equivalent:
a) A and B are independent
b) A' and B are independent

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am unsure of where to start.

Comment: Start with the definition of independent events

Answer (score 0):

$A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

Now, we always have $P(B) = P(A \cap B) + P(A' \cap B)$

So, if we assume $A$ and $B$ are independent:

$P(A' \cap B) = P(B) - P(A \cap B) = P(B) - P(A)P(B) = (1-P(A))P(B) = P(A')P(B)$

Therefore, $A'$ and $B$ are independent.